# Não consigo resolver esse erro do mysqli_query()

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um tutorial que é em uma versão antiga do PHP, um clone do Twitter.
Tenho agora, dois aquivos, um que faz a conexão com o banco de dados e o da página de registros.
Segue os códigos e dentro da página de registros tem uma possibilidade de resposta que não sei resolver.
Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

bd.class.php

```
<?php

class bd{
    //host
    private $host = 'localhost';
    //usuario
    private $user = 'root';
    //senha
    private $password = '';
    //banco de dados
    private $database = 'twitter_clone';

    //Conectando ao Banco de dados
    public function conecta_mysql(){
        //caso não haja conexão exibir o erro
        $con = mysqli_connect($this -> host, $this -> user, $this -> password) or die("Erro ao conectar ao servidor: ".mysql_error());
        //caso não encontre o banco de dados exibir o erro
        mysqli_select_db($con, $this -> database) or die('Erro ao selecionar o banco de dados'.mysql_error());
        //usando os mesmos caracteres
        mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8");
        mysqli_query($con,"SET 'character_set_connection=utf8");
        mysqli_query($con, "SET 'character_set_client=utf8");
        mysqli_query($con, "SET 'character_set_results=utf8");
        return $con;

    }
}   

?>
```

registra_usuario.php

```
<?php

require_once('bd.class.php');

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

//instância da classe bd
$objBd = new bd();
$objBd -> conecta_mysql(); //conectando ao bd

//Inserindo registros
$sql = "insert into usuarios(usuario, email, senha)values('$usuario', '$email', '$senha')";

//Conferindo o registro
if(mysqli_query($sql)){
    echo 'Usiário registrado com sucesso';
} else {
    echo "Erro no registro";
}

// tentei fazer do jeito a baixo, mas nãos ei como faço para chamar a variável dentro da função no arquivo bd.class.php
// $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


?>
```

O erro que aparece é:

````
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter_clone\registra_usuario.php on line 17```
````

Comment: a função mysqli_query() espera dois parametros e você só passou um, você inseriu a query($sql) mas não passou a conexão.

Comment: eu pesquisei isso, mas quando eu chamo a variável de conexão que está dentro da função no outro arquivo apresenta outro erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O mysqli_query no seu estilo procedural necessita que você informe o link de conexão no primeiro parâmetro. Referência: [Manual PHP - mysqli query](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)

No seu caso acredito que o código ficaria assim:

```
if(mysqli_query($objBd->conecta_mysql(), $sql)){
    echo 'Usuário registrado com sucesso';
} else {
    echo "Erro no registro";
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!! deu certo! Pena que meu voto não computa pra vc :/ ainda to num nível baixo

Comment: da pra marcar a resposta como correta eu acho, se der muito obrigado =)